# How to update related record field once record is deleted using flow?

Tags: visual-workflow

I have 2 Objects based on Lookup relationship i.e 1) Assign 2) Inventory.

Relation is 1 inventory can be assigned to many (1 to many).

Inventory has picklist values called "status" contains 2 values i.e "Assigned" and "Backup". So when any inventory is assigned, value changes from "Backup" to "Assigned".

Whenever any record of assign object is deleted, automatically related object (Inventory) field "status" should get updated from "Assigned" to "Backup".

Or else I will need to manually change the status of inventory object from "assigned" to "backup" whenever any record is deleted from assign, which I don't want.

I tried the flow, but I am confused exactly which option I should select. For reference I had attached the snaps. [image] [image] [image]

Comment: I've removed the tags that didn't appear to be relevant. Tags are supposed to describe what the question is about, and helps people to determine if they're in the right place (both for others with similar problems, and those who have knowledge and could possibly help).